# Another JCTI Puzzle

Tags: pattern, matches

It is "find the next box matching the trend" sort of thing.
The question as given is:

[image]

I need to fill the blank area with the correct box given from 6 options:

[image]

What I get from the question is that there is an color inverse of every box given, i.e. for every box in this collection, there is another box of the same pattern but which is negative of that box. But only for the black box there is no negative. So it implies that the answer should be white one(Option 1). However the thing that confuses me is that why are there two black boxes? Please solve this puzzle and state if my reasoning is correct or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before reading your line of reasoning I was thinking the exact same things you were. I'd pick answer 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the answer is

> 5. All black.

Reasoning:

> Including the missing shape, there are 9 boxes.  So I group the patterns into group of 3s.  Going by your logic, add a box to its negative cousin, you will end up with a black box (or white box).  Seeing as there are already 2 black boxes, the result of the third group should also be black.

Comment: How do you group them? Even though they're 9, they seem to be scrambled, unsorted.

Comment: I did not take the arrangment into consideration. I just grouped them based on: its pattern + its negative = black box.

Comment: Why doesn't full-white work? I think that full-black + full-white => full-black

Comment: I agree with this. "Positive", "Negative" and "Overlay between Positive and Negative (which is always black)". Even if it's not the expected answer, it's a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that the inversion has the answer.  There are an odd number of pieces, and if the answer were an inversion, all of the pieces would be grouped in pairs.  9 boxes do add up to a larger box, but I don't see a pattern emerging by arranging the boxes into a larger box.

It could be that the inverted piece is moved, changed in scale, or rotated through each iteration.  That would explain why on the left there appears to be a simple inversion: the piece is a square, and so rotating the inverted portion would maintain the same appearance.

My intuition tells me the answer is

> Option 3

Answer (score 0):

They’re orthographic drawings grouped in threes.  (Google if needed.)  The answer is 5.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Do you mind adding an explanation please? While it is certainly possible to Google this, adding an explanation of what you mean by orthographic drawings would contribute towards this being a complete and high-quality answer and it would be much more well-received too. Good luck and happy puzzling! :)